# Why DataoutputStream and BufferedWriter creation order is important?

Tags: java, sockets, client, bufferedwriter, dataoutputstream

I'm trying to create a simple client where at first I comunicate to a server:

1. A filename
2. The sequence of chunks which compose the file

So for the first one I thought to use to a BufferedWriter: this choice was made since I can't use on the server a InputStreamReader from the moment that the readLine() method is deprecated. However, for the second one I used a OutputStreamWriter since it is the better (only?) one choice to write a byte array on a socket.

So, this is the first version of my client code:

```
public class Client
{
    private static final int PART_SIZE = 1000000; // 1MB

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        final Path file = Paths.get(args[0]);
        final String filenameBase = file.getFileName().toString();
        final byte[] buf = new byte[PART_SIZE];    
        Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),8080);
        System.out.println("Socket created");
        int partNumber = 0;
        Path part;
        int bytesRead;
        byte[] toWrite;

        try (
            final InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file);
            final BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            final DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ) {
            System.out.println("closed="+socket.isClosed());
            bw.write(filenameBase,0,filenameBase.length());
            //other stuff for the chunk creation and spedition
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I run this code, this exception occours:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:121)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:316)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.close(BufferedWriter.java:266)
    at PAD.Charlie.Client.App.main(App.java:50)
```

The strange thing is that **if I change the order between the `BufferedWriter` and the `DataOutputStream` inside the `try` everthing works fine!**

Actually the idea has come because I remembered something about it from the java course, but I can't really remember the details! Can you help me about this doubt that I have? Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you are doing is borderline crazy.  You appear to be intending to write both text and binary data the same stream:

- It is going to be difficult to control the interleaving of the two kinds of data since you are using a buffered writer at that point in the stack.
- Even if you get the interleaving right, the "other end" has the problem of unpicking it to separate the text and binary.

---

You attempt to justify your decision use two stream stacks on the output stream as follows:

> So for the first one I thought to use to a BufferedWriter: this choice was made since I can't use on the server a InputStreamReader from the moment that the readLine() method is deprecated. However, for the second one I used a OutputStreamWriter since it is the better (only?) one choice to write a byte array on a socket.

I don't follow your logic.  But the fact that one approach doesn't work does not necessarily mean that (any) other one will.

If you want a solution that will work, then I can think of a few.  The simplest is to use `DataOutputStream` *only* on the client side, and use `writeUTF` to write the file name and `writeInt` + `write` to write the chunks.  Indicate the end of file by sending a chunk size of zero.

(You could also send the file as one big chunk if you know beforehand how many bytes you will be sending.)

The server-side code should mirror the client-side in its calls on a `DataInputStream`.

---

But the reason for difference in behaviour that you are seeing is that the order of the declarations in the `try` initializations determines the order in which the streams are closed at the end of the `try` block.

- If the writer is closed first then:

  ```
  BufferedWriter.close() 
      -> BufferedWriter.flush() -> OutputStreamWriter.write()
      -> OutputStreamWriter.close() -> SocketOutputStream.close()
  DataOutputStream.close() -> SocketOutputStream.close()
  ```

  This is OK because the second set of closes does not need to write any data.
- If the writer is closed second then:

  ```
  DataOutputStream.close() -> SocketOutputStream.close()
  BufferedWriter.close() 
      -> BufferedWriter.flush() -> OutputStreamWriter.write()  // FAIL
  ```

  The failure happens because the flush cannot write data to the socket because you have already (implicitly) closed it.

Comment: Well could you then suggest me a method to write: 1. a string only once 2. a number which is the bytearray size 3. a bytearray 4. repeat 2. until the whole file wast sent

Comment: For the filename use `writeUTF()` and `readUTF()`, and get rid of the readers and writers altogether. For the size, `writeInt()` or `writeLong()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because closing the `BufferedWriter` flushes it, and  if you create the writer first it will be closed last, after the stream, and closing either of them closes the socket. See the stack trace. `DataOutputStream` isn't buffered, so flushing it does nothing.

NB:

> ... since I can't use on the server a InputStreamReader from the moment that the readLine() method is deprecated. However, for the second one I used a OutputStreamWriter since it is the better (only?) one choice to write a byte array on a socket.

None of this makes sense. `InputStreamReader` doesn't have a `readLine()` method, let alone one that is deprecated; and `OutputStreamWriter` writes chars, not bytes.